# Did Maupassant write to his mother about his attraction to women?

Tags: france, literature, reference, date

The book [How the Brain Lost its Mind](https://www.abebooks.com/9780735214552/Brain-Lost-Mind-Sex-Hysteria-0735214557/plp) quotes a letter from Guy de Maupassant, adressed to his mother, in which he explains his inability to resist his attraction to women.

> I am obsessed by women. I cannot pass up their caresses. And when a woman stops me in the street, by chance, despite her fetid breath and her repugnant filth,  I cannot resist for long that silent and powerful call of the flesh that wells up like the waves from below, from the depths of my entrails, and places a blindfold on my eyes, a gag on my conscience […]

Outside of the book, I cannot find any external reference to this letter. I cannot find neither its original content, nor even its date or any other mention of its existence.

Does this letter exist, and if so, what is the full original?

Searches for the any part of the citation only returns [results related to the above-mentioned book](https://www.google.com/search?q=am%20obsessed%20by%20women.%20%22I%20cannot%20pass%20up%20their%20caresses.%22%20And%20when%20a%20woman%20stops%20me%20in%20the%20street&sca_esv=570917586&rlz=1C1ONGR_frFR980FR980&ei=43seZdfWFPCikdUPjo6bmAE&ved=0ahUKEwiX1Iavxt6BAxVwUaQEHQ7HBhMQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=am%20obsessed%20by%20women.%20%22I%20cannot%20pass%20up%20their%20caresses). Even queries such as [Maupassant letter about women](https://www.google.com/search?q=maupassent%20%22letter%22%20obsession%20women) (or [in French](https://www.google.com/search?q=maupassent%20lettre%20%C3%A0%20sa%20m%C3%A8re%2C%20obsession%20femmes)) do not yield any reference to the letter.
ChatGPT first claimed such a letter existed, and gave me January 2, 1885 for a date, but I could not find any such letter among [Maupassant’s correspondence](http://maupassant.free.fr/correspondance1.html). ChatGPT now claims it does not know of any such letter,.

Comment: ChatGPT is notorious for inventing sources that don't exist, so I wouldn't waste any more time on that avenue.

Comment: Definitely. Still, was worth a shot as I did not have any other lead. I managed to find the date it first gave me, it was January 2, 1885, although this probably won’t help.

Comment: Do you have the original book in hand or are you working from a refernce to it? The book, page 213 in the index appears (I only can get snippet views) to reference a source for the quote, from a [1000+ page bio by Marlo Johston](https://www.amazon.com/Guy-Maupassant-Marlo-Johnston/dp/2213628904?ref_=ast_author_mpb).

Comment: @justCal I actually only have the audiobook, I tried looking for references on Google books but I could only access snippets and did not find the reference, so well done. It's probably in there.

Comment: Here's a collection of some 800+ [letters written by Maupassant](http://maupassant.free.fr/correspondance1.html)... assuming that it was really a letter (if it was indeed to his mother it narrows the search, but it could be someone else.)

Comment: Yeah as mentioned in my question I am aware of this website but couldn't find the letter. I'll see if I somehow missed it.

Comment: No, still can’t find it.